# Ошибка: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пишу:

```
frame.ix[[0,1,2], ["Name", "City"]]
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-c18649817b31> in <module>
----> 1 frame.ix[[0,1,2], ["Name", "City"]]

D:\AnacondaPython\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

Как ее можно устранить?

Comment: Этот атрибут убрали из Pandas несколько лет назад. В современных версиях надо использовать .loc / .iloc вместо .ix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с версии Pandas 0.20.0 (дата релиза: 05.05.2017), ["indexer" `DataFrame.ix[]` объявлен устаревшим](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#deprecations):

> **Deprecate `.ix`**
>
> The `.ix` indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict `.iloc` and
> `.loc` indexers. `.ix` offers a lot of magic on the inference of what the
> user wants to do. To wit, .ix can decide to index positionally OR via
> labels, depending on the data type of the index. This has caused quite
> a bit of user confusion over the years. The full indexing
> documentation is here. ([GH14218](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14218))

The recommended methods of indexing are:

- `.loc` if you want to label index
- `.iloc` if you want to positionally index.

---

Пример из документации:

```
In [122]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
   .....:                    'B': [4, 5, 6]},
   .....:                   index=list('abc'))
   .....: 

In [123]: df
Out[123]: 
   A  B
a  1  4
b  2  5
c  3  6

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

устаревший способ (`.ix[]`):

```
In [3]: df.ix[[0, 2], 'A']
Out[3]:
a    1
c    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

того же можно достичь, используя `.loc[]`:

```
In [124]: df.loc[df.index[[0, 2]], 'A']
Out[124]: 
a    1
c    3
Name: A, Length: 2, dtype: int64
```

или `.iloc[]`:

```
In [125]: df.iloc[[0, 2], df.columns.get_loc('A')]
Out[125]: 
a    1
c    3
Name: A, Length: 2, dtype: int64
```

пример того, как получить индексы сразу *нескольких значений* (для `df.iloc[]`):

```
In [22]: df.iloc[[0,2], df.columns.get_indexer(["B", "A"])]
Out[22]:
   B  A
a  4  1
c  6  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Начиная версией pandas 1.0.0 был атрибут `.ix` навсегда удален - см.  [Removal of prior version deprecations/changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).

Значит, ваш код нужно изменить применением другого атрибута - `.loc` или `.iloc`:

```
frame.loc[[0, 1, 2], ["Name", "City"]]  # вместо 0, 1, 2 нужно писать реальные имена строк
                                        # когда они отличаются от их порядковых чисел,
```

или (например)

```
frame.iloc[[0, 1, 2], [5, 8]]      # когда столбец "Name" шестой и столбец "City" девятый
```